# XSL test two conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML. I want to check if the FormField node which has the element named 'Key' and has value of 'response' has a value set for the element named 'Value'. If the value element is empty then return false else return true:

```
<Form>
    <FormField>
        <Value>Jumper</Value>
        <Key>item</Key>
        <Label>Item</Label>
        <Type>string</Type>
    </FormField>
    <FormField>
        <Value>unsuccessful</Value>
        <Key>response</Key>
        <Label>Response</Label>
        <Type>string</Type>
    </FormField>
    <FormField>
        <Value/>
        <Key>notes</Key>
        <Label>Notes</Label>
        <Type>string</Type>
    </FormField>
<Form>
```

So for example the following would return true

```
<FormField>
        <Value>unsuccessful</Value>
        <Key>response</Key>
        <Label>Response</Label>
        <Type>string</Type>
    </FormField>
```

Where as the following would return false

```
<FormField>
        <Value/>
        <Key>response</Key>
        <Label>Response</Label>
        <Type>string</Type>
    </FormField>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "has a value" you mean "contains a text node", then try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="exists(/Form/FormField[Key='response']/Value/text())"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="boolean(/Form/FormField[Key='response']/Value/text())"/>
```

Comment: no by value i mean if the formfield which has key with value of 'response' also has a value in the value field - so in the above example it has the value of 'unsuccessful' so the condition should return true

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, but the term "has a value in the value field" is ambiguous. That's why I qualified my answer. The above expressions will return "true" if the `Value` element in the `FormField` element that has a child `Key` whose string-value is "response" contains a text node (as it does in your example). If you delete the "unsuccessful" text and leave the element empty, the result will be "false".